# CVS diff from inside VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, diff, cvs

Creating an Addin to use your favorite diff tool for doing a diff between the current active document and the last checked in version seems to be one way to go. 
Is there an option in VS2008 that I might configure to do this for me ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at External Tools (Menu: 'Tools -> External Tools...') This lets you configure any external applications, with various variable substitutions to pass in the file name and location. I have some tools set up this way to perform a similar function with subversion (via TortoiseSVN).